# Unknown exception error when Using Cclleemm/ProductTour for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to use this library in my project. But for some reason my app crushes with unknown exception error on this line

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
    CGRect stringRect = [self.title boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, CR_TITLE_FONT_SIZE)
                                                 options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                              attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:CR_TITLE_FONT_SIZE] }
                                                 context:nil];
```

When I press to continue this is what is being displayed on the screen:

```
Uncaught exception: *** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
```

link to the library : https://github.com/Cclleemm/ProductTour

Comment: The problem is that `[UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:CR_TITLE_FONT_SIZE]` is returning `nil`. Fix it by specifying a valid font.

Comment: BTW - why do you have code that checks for a specific iOS version? Don't do that. Check to see if the method exists instead.

Comment: I didn't write this code. It came with the library figured I should get it working before looking into making any changes. The fontName is specified but let me double check that.

Comment: You were correct. I changed `attributes:nil` and it works. But why isn't it working with the font. I copied the font over to my project inside the Supporting Files folder

Comment: In response to you second comment what do you by "check to see if the method exists.."?

Comment: `if ([self.title respondsToSelector:@selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:)]) { // use it } else { // use old method }`.

Comment: There is no expression though. It does not let me do that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: If statement need to have some sort of expression i.e If(true) or if (number >= 1) something like that right. The one you have above doesn't check anything.

Comment: What I posted is just fine. Try it. `respondsToSelector:` returns a `BOOL`.